# If $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$, and $g(x)$ is not continuous at $a$, then can $f(x)g(x)$ not be continuous at $a$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

If $f(x)$ is continuous at $a$, and $g(x)$ is not continuous at $a$, then $f(x)g(x)$ is not continuous at $a$. Is this right? Why?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Trying some examples is always a good way to start.

Comment: Consider $f(x)\equiv1$ and $f(x)\equiv0$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Many counter examples.  If $f(x)=0$ then $f(x)g(x) =0$ is always continuous whatever $g(x)$ is.  If $f(a)=0$ and $g(x)$ only discontinuity is at $a$ then $f(x)g(x)$ will be continuous at all points but $a$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^+_-}f(x)g(x)= 0\lim_{x\to 0^+_-}g(x)=0 = f(a)g(a)$ so $f(x)g(x)$ is continuous. Now if $f(a)\ne 0$ then... hmmm.

Comment: Another one: $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(x)$. Then $f(x)g(x)=|\sin x|$. Very continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true if $f(a)= 0$.  We can have $g(x)$ continuous at all points other than $a$ and those as the product of continuous functions are continuous we would have $f(x)g(x)$ continuous everywhere but at $x=a$.  But then as $f(a)g(a)=0\cdot g(a) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)\lim_{x\to a^-}g(x)=0\cdot \lim_{x\to a^-}g(x)=0=f(a)g(a)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)\lim_{x\to a^+}g(x)=0\cdot \lim_{x\to a^+}g(x)=0=f(a)g(a)$ we have $f(x)g(x)$ continuous everywhere.

But if we add the condition that $f(a)\ne 0$ the statement is true.

If $g(x)$ is not continuous at $x=a$ then there is a value $E$ so that there for any $\delta > 0$ there will always be a $w$ so that $|w-a|< \delta$ and $|g(w)-g(a)| > E$.

Let $f(a)= K\ne 0$.

I claim there is for any $\delta > 0$ we can find a $w$ so that $|w-a| < \delta$ and $|f(w)g(w) - f(a)g(a)| > \frac 34|K|E$.  (Three quarters is totally arbitrary.  Any $r: 0< r < 1$ will do.

$f$ is continuous at $a$ so we can find a $D$ so that for all $x$: $|x-a| <D$ we have $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(x)-K| < \frac 14|K|$ or $\frac 34|K| < |f(x)| < 1\frac 14|K|$.

But for for any $\delta: 0 < \delta < D$ we have a $w$ so that $|w-a| < \delta < D$ but $|g(w)-g(a)|> |E|$.  But $\frac 34|K| < |f(w)| < 1\frac 14|K|$. so $\frac 34|K||g(w)| < |f(w)g(w)| < 1\frac 14|K||g(w)$ and $|f(a)g(a)|=|K||g(a)|$

$|f(w)g(w)-f(a)g(a)|= |(f(w)g(w) - f(w)g(a)) + (f(w)g(a)-f(a)g(a))|\ge ||f(w)g(w)-f(w)g(a)| - |f(w)g(a)-f(a)g(a)|| > \frac 34|K|E$.